# Pre / Post increment operator on structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, operator-precedence, post-increment, pre-increment

I'm new to C 
didn't get what going on here

```
struct person {
    int age;
};

main ()
{
    struct person p , *ptr;
    ptr = &p;

  printf ("%d \n" , ++ptr->age );
  printf("%d" , ptr++->age);

  return 0;
}
```

> How Both printf statements prints 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression

```
++ptr->count;
```

is equivalent to

```
++( ptr->count );
```

So it increases data member `count` of the structure pointed to by `ptr`.

operator `->` in expression `++ptr->count` is a postfix operator that has higher priority than any unary operator including pre-increment operator `++`.

In this expression

```
ptr++->count;
```

there are two postfix operators: post-increment operator `++` and operator `->`. They are evaluated left to right. The value of the post-increment operator ++ is the value of its operand before incrementing. So this expressions returns the value of data member `count` of the structure pointed to by `ptr` before its incrementing. The pointer itself is incremented.

According to the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
>   As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it)....